# Boost Library : Android

Tags: android, boost, boost-spirit

One question.

Does Boost C++ library works in Android OS?

I know that Android NDK doesn't support all C++ lib's.

Thanks

Comment: It might be helpful to know which version and compiler you are using and if STL is available.

Comment: I am using Eclipse IDE with latest Android NDK package for Android app development.

Comment: Boost is not a library, but a collection of libraries. Most of them are compilable with the NDK. There was some issue with `Boost.Serialization`, due to the lack of wide chars support in past NDK version, although I don't know what the status of this issue is now.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming (from the [boost-spirit](/questions/tagged/boost-spirit) tag) that you're interested in this particular library, the answer is simple:

Boost spirit (and it's constituent support libraries) is a header only library and is supported as long as pick a compiler that is capable of compiling it.

Comment: ... and a development host with plenty of RAM and some time to kill.   Boost spirit is tough on compilers! ;)

Comment: @marko True :) Though c++11 + `BOOST_RESULT_OF_USE_DECLTYPE` + `BOOST_SPIRIT_USE_PHOENIX_V3` + `BOOST_SPIRIT_NO_PREDEFINED_TERMINALS` does wonders. As does [staying away from semantic actions](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8259585/85371) and factoring your grammar well.

Comment: Semantic actions is the particularly smart bit of Qi.   I was getting the long compile times on a relatively small grammar, using clang.  It would be much worse with GCC.  Things got even more interesting running clang's static analyser on the project.

Comment: @sehe is there any question (with detailed answer) about how to achieve best results in sense of optimality (compilation time, compile time memory, executable size, runtime memory etc.) on SO?

Comment: I think I just summed it up :) I believe I have answered a similar question once, but the summary should be rather apt. There has been some discussion on the mailing list. Invariably, the devs point at the compiler samples for good ideas.